# CRT deprecation warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, deprecated, crt

According to [Security Enhancements in the CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Secure Template Overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it is possible to disable warnings associated with functions deprecated due to safety issue using _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. It is also possible to replace some of the functions with their safer counterpart using _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES. However, does anybody know if both can be used simultaneously. That is, if I first specify _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES and then _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS, will those functions that can be replaced be replaced and for remaining cases the warnings are suppressed. I'm not sure how to test this, because if I add both, all warnings will effectively be suppressed, but I don't know if it is only due to the second flag.

Comment: You can check that with IntelliSense (going to the definition of a function) or in the debugger (stepping into the function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use both, and they are doing exactly what you've expected.

You can take a look at `crtdefs.h` header file. In case you define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` it simply doesn't generate a warning in place of `_CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE` references.

The `_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES` controls other macros, like `__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_FUNC_ ...` and alike.